# Auto revocation of distribution certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution, csr, certificate-revocation

My role is **[member](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/)** in apple developer program.

I had been given distribution certificate and adhoc provisioning profile.

I released the app but later on certificate has been revoked.

I am wondering what would have caused this ?

[image]

As far as I know development certificates can be created and removed by a person who is having **member** role also which is me.

sometimes If xcode autocreates a certificate it might revoke the existing certificate and add the new one.

But in my case its not development certificate that have got revoked but distribution certificate that got revoked.

A person with **member** access can submit **CSR** for Distribution but can not either add new one or revoke existing one.so auto revocation of distribution certificate is not possible.

But I can see a new distribution certificate in the member center on the same day.

Which makes me think whether somebody revoked it manually and added the new one or xcode did it.

somebody with experience please clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

Some One have login into xcode and run it after that so its revoke certificate automatically. remove login from xcode and set certificate manually in xcode.

Comment: its a distribution certificate not development certificate I don't think someone with member access can create distribition certificate even they're logged in xcode